# Laravel passport production : The resource owner or authorization server denied the request

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-passport

i build an API with Laravel and i get error only in prod : log file

```
The resource owner or authorization server denied the request {"exception":"[object] (League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Exception\\OAuthServerException(code: 9): The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. at /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:243)
```

i use Postman when i want login, i still get loading without any response, i check my database, oauth_access_tokens Auth passowrd client is enregistered, but i don't get a response token.

- Passport Version: ^8.3
- Laravel Version: ^7.0
- PHP Version: 7.4
- Database Driver & Version: PostgreSQL 12